# python - re-dimensionar elemento con un numero aleatorio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Quiero re-dimensionar el frame que cree, la idea es que tome un numero aleatorio para pasarlo como valor `height()`, esto lo debe de hacer en un determinado ciclo en este caso 100 veces con un tiempo de actualización del valor cada segundo`time.sleep(1)`, esto debe de actualizar gráficamente el tamaño del frame pero no lo hace.

Aquí dejo mi código espero puedan apoyarme:

```
import sys
import random
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFrame
from PyQt5 import uic


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setGeometry(200,200,10,50)
        frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:lightblue')

        n=0
        while n<100:
            s = random.randint(0,100)
            frame.resize(10,s)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(s)
            n+=1


app = QApplication([])
principal = Principal()
principal.resize(600,400)
principal.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep()` es una tarea bloqueante y este tipos de tareas no se deben ejecutar en el hilo principal llamado hilo de la GUI ya que bloquean las otras tareas que tiene que hacer como por ejemplo mostrar los widgets, redibujar, recibir eventos del mouse, etc.

Las GUIs ofrecen alternativas para ese tipo de tareas sin necesidad de ser bloqueantes, en el caso de Qt, y por lo tanto PyQt, se debe usar `QTimer`:

```
import sys
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(200,200,10,50)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:lightblue')

        self.timer = QTimer(self)    
        self.n = 0
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def on_timeout(self):
        if self.n < 100:
            s = random.randint(0,100)
            self.frame.resize(10,s)
            print(s)
            self.n += 1
        else:
            self.timer.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    principal = Principal()
    principal.resize(600,400)
    principal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte